# How can I filter Twitter posts without links?

Tags: twitter, search

I was trying to search for Tweets via Twitter's search site: http://twitter.com/search

Well if you use a keyword called `filter:links` in your search text box you get all posts which have links. Its useful when you are searching about a news you haven't heard of (Twitter trends mostly) that is quite active: you'd have people Tweet their reactions to it most of the time, however you'd be interested in the Tweets which point to the exact news article on the web to actually learn about the news. Hence this comes in handy.

But I want quite the opposite of this. Does Twitter provide anyway to express this requirement? I tried `-filter:links`, needless to say it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I tried

> [-filter:links india](https://twitter.com/search/-filter%3alinks%20india)

and it returns tweets without any links in them. Tweets containing images show pic.twitter.com links though.

You can also try to [exclude tweets containing "http" in your timeline.](http://kottke.org/12/07/turn-your-twitter-stream-into-your-friends-linkblog)

> [-http india](https://twitter.com/search?q=-http%20india&src=typd)

Comment: but sometimes I noticed links to pics in the post...mostly belonging to pic.twitter.com

Comment: You can try this link to view tweets in your timeline without links - https://twitter.com/search/timeline/-http